# Jquery function messes up my other code

Tags: jquery

Problem solved.

When I put the code below into my system, all my jquery just stop to work. Nothing happends when I try to trigger any other event.

The file sok_kund_db.php is error free.

```
$("#avbokad_kund_circle").click(function () {
    var visa = '';
    visa += 'klar_kund_circle=' + $(this).attr('value') + '&' + 'mass_id=' + '<?php echo $_GET['
    mass_id ']; ?>';
    $.post('sok_kund_db.php', visa, function (data) {
        $("#resultat").html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

I can not see where I did wrong.

Comment: Define 'stop to work' - what happens? This code makes a call to `sok_kund_db.php` - does that execute successfully?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Tried debugging with the console?

Comment: I've explained my problem better now. j08691: I can not find anything worng, it's like everything dies.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please accept one of the answers (if any of them were correct), or post your own answer with what you did and accept that, or if there was just some typo or something in code not even shown please delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Put double quotes around the php term
The single quotes around mass_id are interfering with the string you're building

```
"<?php echo $_GET['mass_id']; ?>"
```

Alternatively you can do this:

```
'<?php echo $_GET["mass_id"]; ?>'
```

Comment: But the quotes inside the `<?php ... ?>` tag are never seen by the browser, so how do they interfere with the JS string being built?

Answer (score 0):

try to change this

```
'<?php echo $_GET['mass_id']; ?>'
```

for this

```
'<?php echo $_GET["mass_id"]; ?>'
```